# autolayout - figuring out which constraints supersede which

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, programmatically-created

I'm messing around with a really simple app to learn how to use AVFoundation (only been coding at all for about 14 weeks).

Included is a screenshot to help visualize my problem - my vertical constraints work just fine, and my horizontal constraints appear for two buttons that I have. However, my horizontal constraints (which I'm using to center a few objects) do not seem to work for the two labels I have underneath each button.

I wonder if the problem is that some constraints (perhaps the way I've created them) take priority over others and prevent some constraints from appearing properly? Really not sure here.

[image]

```
-(void)setConstraints {
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    UIButton *cameraButton = self.cameraButton;
    UILabel *camera = self.videoLabel;
    UIButton *libraryButton = self.libraryButton;
    UILabel *library = self.libraryLabel;

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(camera, cameraButton, libraryButton, library);

    //set up top button to be horizontally centered
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[cameraButton]-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];
    //set up top button vertical from top of superview
    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-175-[cameraButton]"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                                    views:views]];
    //set up top button label to be horizontally centered
    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"|-[camera]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    //set up second button to be horizontally centered
    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"|-[libraryButton]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                                       views:views]];
    //set up label for second button to be horizontally centered
    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"|-[library]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    //set up vertical constraints by spacing ALL objects appropriately
    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[cameraButton]-[camera]-150-[libraryButton]-[library]"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

}
```

Comment: "horizontal constraints do not seem to work" The phrase "do not seem to work" is meaningless. Say clearly what you expect / want that is different from what is happening.

Comment: @matt edited. If you'd read past the first few sentences and into the code just a little, you'd see that my comments clearly outline that I'm trying to center everything.

Comment: Well, as you've already been told, your labels _are_ centered. The problem is that the _text_ is not centered within the labels. But that has nothing to do with constraints!

Comment: Yep. Today was my first day really looking at it, so I'm still getting the hang of it. Powerful tool...btw, love your books @matt

Comment: Thanks, glad if they're helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you wanted these views to appear centered. But that isn't what a "|-[view]-|" constraint will do. What you just told the view is, "I want you to fill the entire width of your superview, modulo the default padding". If you were to set a background color on your labels you'd see them extending the entire width of the view.

The easiest solution for you  here is to set the text layout to center.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try it. I may also just use spacing items. Wish I could post the code in a comment but it's way too messy. It would just involve creating two blank UIViews that have nothing in them and doing something along the lines of:

@"H:|[spacer1][label][spacer2(==spacer1)]|"

This seems, however, like it's too much to have to do for each item that I want centered.